# Hide navigation bar but keep back button - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Is it possible to hide/remove a `NavigationBar` but keep the back button visible?

I have tried hiding the whole navigation bar and adding a custom back button using a `NavigationLink` but then I get a back button on my first view (`ProductList`) when pressing back which wasn't there before.

If I have to create a custom back button is there a different way than `NavigationLink` like I am using in `Tab1View` to eliminate a back button appearing in `ProductList` when navigating back?

This is the first view that uses a `NavigationLink` to a `TabBar`:

```
struct ProductList: View {
    ScrollView{
        VStack{
            ForEach(matchedItems) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: TabView(product: item)){
                        Text("MoveToTabView")
                   }
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

I am then using a `TabBar` where I am hiding the `NavigationBar`:

```
 struct TabView: View {
    var product: ProductModel
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            // TAB 1
            Tab1View(product: product).tabItem {
                    Text(product.detailTabNames[0])
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            // TAB 2
            Tab2View(product: product).tabItem {
                    Text(product.detailTabNames[1])
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the final `View` from the `Tabbar` where I am adding my own custom back button:

```
struct Tab1View: View {
    var product: ProductModel
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Text("Tab1View")
            NavigationLink(destination: ProductList()){
                Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Back button is integral part of NavigationBar. If you hide bar you need custom back button.

Comment: @Asperi - Thank you, I am already adding a custom back button using a NavigationLink, it is in the final bit of code: NavigationLink(destination: ProductList()){ Image(systemName: "chevron.backward") }. By doing this it causes my original view ProductList to have a back button, where there was original no back button if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seemed to have resolved my problem by following [this](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/07/17/navigation-in-swiftui/) and using `@Environment`

So instead of using a `NavigationLink` in my final tab like this:

```
ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Text("Tab1View")
            NavigationLink(destination: ProductList()){
                Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
            }
}
```

I am now using a button that dismisses the view like this using `@Environment`:

```
struct Tab1View: View {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation

    var product: ProductModel
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Text("Tab1View")
            Button(action: {
                self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("PressMe")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this allows me to hide the `NavigationBar` in the TabView the same way:

```
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep the back navigation capability, you will still need the Navigation bar. The way to do this, with your desired view is:

```
.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
```

Outside that, you'll want to leave the navigation bar visible. If you don't, SwiftUI will not display the navigation link to go back.

Comment: Thanks, this does hide the `NavigationBar` like I wanted, but unfortunately it keeps the `NavigationBar` padding at the top so everything is shifting down. If I hide the the `NavigationBar` all together it removes the padding which is what I am after.

Comment: In that case, your best bet is to use a ZStack to place a button at the top to act like a back button.

Comment: Thank you, I am already have a ZStack and a NavigationLink, it is in the final bit of code: NavigationLink(destination: ProductList()){ Image(systemName: "chevron.backward") }. By doing this it causes my original view ProductList to have a back button, where there was original no back button if that makes sense?